# I don't understand this overflow behaviour

Tags: html, css

... because the box (sidebar-1) has a given width of 180px!

Why not ...

Het
grote
natuurgebeuren

instead of ...

Het
grote natuurgebeuren

Have a look at > http://www.jeannies.nl/txp/teksten

CSS:

```
ul.article_list li {
color: #444;
font-size: 24px;
line-height: 1.2em;
padding-top: 7px;
padding-left: 6px; /* to line-up with site-name!  */
letter-spacing: 0;
text-transform: none;   
letter-spacing: 0;
margin-bottom: 6px;}

ul.article_list li a {
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 0px solid #999;}

ul.article_list li a:hover, ul.article_list li.active a {
color: #444;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
```

[edit]
Solved ... thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a `&nbsp;` in your text

```
Het grote&nbsp;natuurgebeuren
```

the browsers sees this as a single word.
 
remove it and natuurgebeuren will drop to the next line

in general a `&nbsp;` is not necessary in this case as you have only a single space

Comment: @BoltClock...you know you want to elaborate on that...share your wisdom!!!

Comment: @stratton ... how did you find out? Mmm ... oké ... source of course ... *sigh! But now I've to find out why it has been put there in the first place ...

Comment: @redfox how are you creating this navigation? are you using a CMS like Joomla or a blog like wordpress?

Comment: @stratton ... Textpattern it is and with a preference I didn't know till now ... 'prevent widowed words in article titles' ... it was checked 'yes' ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider looking at something like the `word-wrap` property as well, such as:

```
//This will actually break the word and wrap it
word-wrap : break-word;
```

**[Word-Wrap Documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#overflow-wrap0)**

Comment: Although `word-wrap` is good, it wouldn't break the word how redfox requires - it would just break it at the point where it stops fitting

Comment: I was just offering this as an alternative solution. Still exploring other avenues :)